# Prestashop/Cpanel Server Permissions Error?

Tags: cpanel

My website is getting a 500 internal server error. I currently use cpanel and prestashop as the platform.

I really don't have much experience to apache, so I really didn't know what to do but here is the error log.

```
[Sat Nov 25 22:46:00.301861 2023] [core:crit] [pid 58170:tid 22771220252416] (13)Permission denied: [client 52.167.144.168:0] AH00529: /home/pki08/public_html/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/home/pki08/public_html/' is executable
```

I did check the permissions for /public_html  its 755 for the folders and the permissions for the files are 644.